# Binding list to textbox won't update if ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a custom control in WPF. I bind a `List<IMyInterface>` to a `dependency property`. This in turn binds again to a `ListBox` which shows all the items as expected.

I now want to bind 1 item from this list to a `Textblock`, so I bind the entire list to the `textblock`. I have a `converter` in this which extracts the single item I want.

It has worked fine but for a few reasons, I want to use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`

Oddly, when I change a value in my `ObservabaleCollection` at run time, the value is shown in the `ListBox` (success) but not in my `textblock`. The `converter` is not even hit!

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.Errors = new ObservableCollection<IEventDetail>();
        this.Errors.CollectionChanged += Errors_CollectionChanged;
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += ((o, e) =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                this.Errors.Add(new MyEvents("example of some detail", "Failed title"));
            });

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                this.Errors.Add(new MyEvents("Another example", "Failed title 2"));
            });
        });
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();//background worker for testing/debugging only
    }

    private void Errors_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("Errors");
    }

    private ObservableCollection<IEventDetail> _errors;
    public ObservableCollection<IEventDetail> Errors
    {
        get
        {
            return this._errors;
        }
        set
        {
            this._errors = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Errors");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
            return;

        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

And the xaml is simply

```
 <local:Notify Events="{Binding Errors}" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
```

As you can see, I've tried to use the `CollectionChanged` event to then force fire the `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but it's firing in my `Converter` yet the `ListBox` is updating fine (so I know the binding is fine)

This is the `UserControls` xaml

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Events, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType=UserControl}, Mode=Default, Converter={StaticResource MostRecentConverter}}" Grid.Row="0" />

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Events, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1,AncestorType=UserControl}, Mode=Default}" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventTitle}" Style="{StaticResource txtBckRed}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Do I need to do something else?

Comment: The problem must be on xaml, onpropertychanged is implicit in observableCollection. (cany you post the xaml?) try to set explicti two way binding and UpdataSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged

Comment: @Xilmiki, thanks but, the binding **is** working on the `ListBox`, but not the `Textblock`. So I'm not sure why I'd need 2 way binding or to even use `UpdateSourceTrigger`

Comment: Plese try to set explicit two way binding and UpdataSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged in TextBox Binding, i had the same problem on my WPF project.

Comment: I have, it doesn't help. How would `UpdateSourceTrigger ` help as I'm changing the value in the code behind? And it's not binding 2 ways?

Comment: @Dave it `TextBlock` it bound only to `Events` property change (not its items) so it won't trigger unless you create new collection is created. Even manually raising property changed event for `Errors` won't work as UI will see that collection instance is actually the same

Comment: @dkozl, right... yes. This makes sense, initially I was creating a brand new List<> each time for this reason. I was hoping my 'hack' of using the `CollectionChanged` would suffice. But, if this is the case, why does it update correctly with the `ListBox`?

Comment: Reacting to `INotifyCollectionChanged` is characteristic to `ItemsSource` property. What does your converter do? You could create your collection type based on `ObservableCollection<T>` that adds custom property that does what converter would do or in user control subscribe to `CollectionChanged` event and manually refresh binding expression for `TextBlock`

Comment: @dkozl, the converter simply takes the `List<IMyInterface>` as a parameter, and sorts one of the `IMyInterface` properties (which is `DateTime`). It returns the most recent as a string. Since it doesn't appear possible with the approach I've taken, please do move your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `TextBlock` it **bound only to `Events` property change (not its items)** so it won't trigger unless new instance of collection is created. Reacting to `INotifyCollectionChanged` is characteristic to `ItemsSource` property.

**Solution 1**

Leave everything as it is at the moment just give `TextBlock` some name

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ...}" x:Name="myTextBlock"/>
```

and subscribe to `CollectionChanged` event inside your `UserControl` where you manually force binding target to update

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EventsProperty =
                               DependencyProperty.Register("Events", 
                                   typeof(IEnumerable), 
                                   typeof(MyUserControl), 
                                   new PropertyMetadata(EventsPropertyChanged));

    private static void EventsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MyUserControl)d).EventsPropertyChanged(e);
    }

    private void EventsPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var newCollection = args.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (newCollection != null)
            newCollection.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => myTextBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
    }

    public IEnumerable Events
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(EventsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EventsProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

**Solution 2**

Create your own collection class inherited from `ObservableCollection<T>` with custom property that would do what your converter does

```
public class MyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private string _convertedText;

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        this.ConvertedText = ...; // <- do here what your IValueConverter does
    }

    public string ConvertedText
    {
        get { return _convertedText; }
        private set
        {
            _convertedText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ConvertedText"));
        }
    }
}
```

and bind `TextBlock.Text` to `Events.ConvertedText` property instead, without need for converter