# Catch ChangeEvents from ObservableDictionary in MVVM C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a software (with GUI) containing metainformation about products. Part of that information are some ratings of components of that product.

I want to display this ratings somehow like this for everey product someone clicked on:

```
Part a: 100%
Part b: 20%
Part c: -
Part d: 40%
```

It can be lots of values and i don't want to create an own variable for every possible rating.

My problem is that i have lots of missing values but i want the GUI allways to look the same so i thought of an observable dictionary to store my data (coming from a webinterface on the fly for the product someone clicks on) and bind wpf elements to the values of that dictionary.

I found an implementation of an ObservableDictionary in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10616706/7408462) which contains a link to the [Implementation](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/).

---

**Here are some parts of my code to show where my problem is:**

My View implementation looks like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Ratings, Converter={StaticResource ObservableDictionaryConverter}, ConverterParameter=Key}"/>
```

Where Ratings is my Observable Dictionary, Key is my hardcoded Component (e.g. "Part a") and ObservableDictionaryConverter is a converter returning the rating if it exists or "-" if it doesn't.

My ModelView Implementation looks like this

```
public class Foo : Bindable
{
    ObservableDictionary<string, ComponentRatings> _ratings
    public ObservableDictionary<string, ComponentRatings> Ratings
        {
            get {return _ratings; }
            set
            {
                _ratings = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
}
```

And the Model:

```
ViewModel.Ratings= new ObservableDictionary<string, ComponentRatings>();
foreach (var e in foo)
{
    ViewModel.Ratings.Add(e.Drive.ToString(), e);
}
```

---

**1.)** If i run my code the gui only updates itself when the Dictionary is instantiated due to the OnPropertyChanged() in my ModelView property. But when i Add new Elements to the Dict, my GUI should update itself and show them. So how do i catch the CollectionChanged events from the Observable Dictionary in my ModelView?

**2.)** The hardcoded Keys in the XAML are not really nice but i couldn't come up with a better way to allways have all my ratings in the GUI even if they don't exist. Is there some better, more flexible way to implement something like this?

Comment: `TextBlock` doesn't listen to `CollectionChanged`. Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661607/binding-list-to-textbox-wont-update-if-observablecollection

Comment: Thanks !! That was exactly the problem. Make it an answer and you get your 15 reputation ;-)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `TextBlock` doesn't listen to `CollectionChanged` events. So you need to either manually listen for the changes and update the `TextBlock` in the code behind or, better yet, raise an event that the `TextBlock` can subscribe to from your `ObservableDictionary`.

You can find an example where this is done with a `List` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661607/binding-list-to-textbox-wont-update-if-observablecollection).